# In Powerpoint VBA, how do I make an embedded video start playing?

Tags: vba, video, powerpoint

My Office 365 PowerPoint presentation has a single slide.  The slide includes a shape with embedded (not linked, not OLE) video which I originally inserted from an .mp4 file.  The video starts playing when I click on it but I need to control it from VBA code.  Nothing I've tried (see below) works and of course I get no error messages or any kind of feedback.  How do I start (and stop) the video from code?

```
Sub PlayVideo(Name)
Set Shape = GetShape(Name)
' Shape.MediaType == ppMediaTypeMovie

With Shape.AnimationSettings
    .Animate = msoTrue
    .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
    .AdvanceTime = 0
    .TextLevelEffect = ppAnimateByAllLevels
    With .PlaySettings
        .PlayOnEntry = msoTrue
        .PauseAnimation = msoFalse
        .LoopUntilStopped = msoTrue
    End With
End With
With Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence
    Set AnimationEffect = .AddEffect(Shape:=Shape, effectid:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay)
    With AnimationEffect
        Set Behaviour = .Behaviors.Add(msoAnimTypeCommand)
        With Behaviour
            .CommandEffect.Type = msoAnimCommandTypeVerb
            .CommandEffect.Command = "play"
        End With
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `includes a shape with embedded (not linked, not OLE) video` How was the video embedded?

Comment: @SiddharthRout
I embedded the video like this: Toolbar > Insert tab > Video > This Device > [...\algorithm panel.mp4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start the video use

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Player("algorithm panel").Play
```

To stop the video use

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Player("algorithm panel").Stop
```

Here is an example. Paste this in a module. My video name is `SAMPLE.mp4`

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartVideo()
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Player("SAMPLE").Play
End Sub

Sub StopVideo()
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Player("SAMPLE").Stop
End Sub
```

Next insert 2 action button in the slide and assign the macros

[image]

And we are done.